# Does 'grant create procedure' will also allow to do delete it?

Tags: oracle, permissions

Does `grant create procedure` will also allow to do delete/alter or do I need to run individual Grants for Delete Procedure and Alter procedure?

Comment: So if I give just Grant Create permission then i no longer need to run Grants for Alter and Delete procedures right..

Comment: how hard can it be to test this?

Answer (score 1):

Users can drop objects owned by them, no extra privilege needed for that.

There is such privilege as `Delete Procedure` or `Alter Procedure`.

The privileges `DROP ANY PROCEDURE` and `ALTER ANY PROCEDURE` allow a privileged user to `DROP` and `ALTER` objects owned by other users.